# Active Page/Tab Menu Background Color

Tags: html, css, tabs, bootstrap-5

I have bee struggling with this for hours now. I can't seem to make the active page's menu tab have a white background.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Add the Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Your Navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-info">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
        <img src="image/nav_bar/qsc_burgee_bg_trans.png" width="auto" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
        <strong>QSC</strong>
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
        aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-dark <?php echo ($activePage === 'about_us.html') ? 'active' : ''; ?>" href="#" role="button"
              data-bs-toggle="dropdown">About Us</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="about_us.html">About Us/History</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="contact_us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="forsale.html">Classified Ads</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="board_members.html">Board Members</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-dark <?php echo ($activePage === 'sailsandtrails.html' || $activePage === 'employment.html') ? 'active' : ''; ?>" href="#" role="button"
              data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Sails & Trails Camp</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="sailsandtrails.html">Camp Information</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="employment.html">Employment</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark <?php echo ($activePage === 'openwater.html') ? 'active' : ''; ?>" href="openwater.html">Open Water Swimming</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-dark <?php echo ($activePage === 'sponsors.html' || $activePage === 'openhouse.html' || $activePage === 'member_resources.html') ? 'active' : ''; ?>" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Membership</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="sponsors.html">Join Us</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="openhouse.html">Open House</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="member_resources.html">Member Resources</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark <?php echo ($activePage === 'calendar.html') ? 'active' : ''; ?>" href="calendar.html">Calendar</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-dark <?php echo ($activePage === 'snipefleet.html' || $activePage === 'snipe_regatta_announcements.html' || $activePage === 'snipefleet_members.html' || $activePage === 'snipefleet_regatta_results.html') ? 'active' : ''; ?>" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Snipe Fleet</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="snipefleet.html">Snipe Fleet</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="snipe_regatta_announcements.html">Regatta Announcements</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="snipefleet_members.html">Fleet 231 Members</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="snipefleet_regatta_results.html">QSC Regatta Results</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark <?php echo ($activePage === 'adultsailing.html') ? 'active' : ''; ?>" href="adultsailing.html">Adult Sailing Lessons</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-dark <?php echo ($activePage === 'nature_g/nature_guide.html' || $activePage === 'kayak_tours.html') ? 'active' : ''; ?>" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Other Activities</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="nature_g/nature_guide.html">Wildlife</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="kayak_tours.html">Kayak Tours</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Add the Bootstrap JS and jQuery libraries -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Add the custom JavaScript to set the active class -->
  <script>
    // Get the file name from the current URL
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    var page = path.split("/").pop();

    // Add the 'active' class to the matching nav link based on the page
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.nav-item .nav-link[href="' + page + '"]').addClass('active');
    });
  </script>

  <!-- Add the custom CSS for the active class and hover -->
  <style>
.navbar-nav .nav-link .nav-tabs .nav-item{
  color: black; /* Set the text color to black for all nav links */
}

  .custom-navbar {
    background-color: white;
  }
  
  .nav-tabs .nav-item .nav-link.active,
    .nav-tabs .nav-item .nav-link:hover {
      background-color: white;
      color: #000; /* Change this to your desired text color for active and hover states */
    }
  </style>

</body>

</html>
```

All I have managed to do is get the background to turn white when I hover over the menu tab. I feel like I'm close but I can't quite get there. Hoping for some help!
(Note: I am not an expert at this)

Comment: Is the "active" class correctly being applied via the PHP?

Comment: I don't have a PHP file... should I have one?

Comment: I am referring to the PHP in your anchors: `<?php echo ($activePage === 'openwater.html') ? 'active' : ''; ?>`

Comment: If this isn't a PHP file, then the PHP will not be executed. It is still visible in the output?

Comment: Your styles are applied, when it gets the active class, so @TimR is exactly on point with his comment.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add the `active` class to your active menu item?
Something like this:

```
   <a class="active nav-link dropdown-toggle text-dark <?php echo ($activePage === 'about_us.html') ? 'active' : ''; ?>" href="#" role="button"
          data-bs-toggle="dropdown">About Us</a>
```